# Sautfinsoft PDF Focus .Net Converter text issue

Tags: c#, .net, pdf

So I've been trying to use SautinSoft software to convert a pdf document to a docx document. However, whenever I run this code my word document ends up having squished text. I've attached the images below, any idea what is going on?

```
SautinSoft.PdfFocus f = new SautinSoft.PdfFocus()
f.OpenPdf(@source); 

if (f.PageCount > 0){
    string path = Path.ChangeExtension(source, ".docx");
    f.WordOptions.Format = SautinSoft.PdfFocus.CWordOptions.eWordDocument.Docx;
    f.ToWord(@path);
}
```

[image: Image Description]

This is a docx file after conversion. The image rendered fine, but the text is all squished for some reason. I'm also running on macOS (if that makes a difference). Thank you for anyone that can help!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. You have to make sure to set

```
f.WordOptions.KeepCharScaleAndSpacing = false;
```

Because by default, the converter will scale the font widths based on the PDF fonts rather than your default word doc fonts.

Answer (score 0):

Just load your fonts which you are using in the PDF in "C:/Windows/Fonts" and reboot your PC.
Then to convert your PDF to WORD again.

If it doesn't work for you. Try to use an another way. Specify the path to your folder's font for PDF Focus like :

```
f.WordOptions.Fonts = D:/Fonts;
```